can't get cookies to work. Node/React/Vercel/Render
I did not write the backend, and do not have backend experience. It was 2 man project and now I am trying to gain that experience by deploying it.
I have backend deployed on Render, frontend on Vercel.
Everything worked in development, and in preview as well. It was only after deploying, that the cookie based issues appeared, meaning to test the code I have to keep redeploying as they won't appear in testing.
const path = require('path');

const      express = require('express');
const   bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const     mongoose = require('mongoose');
const      session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const       socket = require('socket.io');
const       multer = require('multer');
const         cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const User = require('./models/user');

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGO_KEY;
const    app = express();
const   http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const     io = socket(server);

let users = [];

const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
  !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) && users.push({ userId, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

const getUser = (userId) => {
  return users.find((user) => user.userId === userId);
};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // when connect
  console.log('a user connected.');

  // take userId and socketId from user
  socket.on('addUser', (userId) => {
    addUser(userId, socket.id);
    io.emit('getUsers', users);
  });

  // send and get message
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
    const user = getUser(receiverId);
    io.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
      senderId,
      text,
    });
  });

  // when disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('a user disconnected!');
    removeUser(socket.id);
    io.emit('getUsers', users);
  });
});

const store = new MongoDBStore({
         uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions',
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const  marketRoutes = require('./routes/market');
const   adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const    authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/message');
const    chatRoutes = require('./routes/chat');
const          user = require('./models/user');

app.use(
  cors({
         origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, // configured to accept credentials from front end for session cookies to work
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(
  session({
               secret: 'my secret',
               resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
                store: store,
               cookie: {
                     maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                   httpOnly: true,   
                     secure: true,  
                   sameSite: 'None', 
              },
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return next();
  }
  User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return next();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.use(marketRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(messageRoutes);
app.use(chatRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then((result) => {
    server.listen(3000);
    console.log('connected!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

So after going round in circles with several AIs, they keep repeating the same thing, to add these lines that I did not originally have:
                   httpOnly: true,   
                     secure: true,  
                   sameSite: 'None', 

This hasn't worked. Without these lines, the app did have full functionality only in Firefox browser. Any other browser I tested it on, you can see the DB data, you can signup/login (POST requests), but you cannot perform any other request, because the controller will check for a req.session.user in pretty much every controller. This relies on cookies to work correctly. The client side will use some hooks to make requests which will call this function
export interface Fetch {
  params: string;
  method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
   data?: object;
}

export const fetchData = async ({ params, method, data }: Fetch) => {
  const isFormData = data instanceof FormData;
  const body = data ? (isFormData ? data : JSON.stringify(data)) : null;

  const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL + params, {
    method,
    headers: isFormData ? undefined : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: 'include', // send cookies to backend
    body,
  });

  const resData = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw resData;
  }

  return resData;
};

The Cors is set to receive credentials. Credentials set to true on Client side. Everything works in Dev/Preview and Firefox with the App code just like this:
app.use(
  session({
               secret: 'my secret',
               resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
                store: store,
               cookie: {
                   maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
              },
  })
);

But the cookies will not work in any non Firefox browser. Then adding the extra cookie config prevents it from working in any environment at all.
I have tried amending the cookie config and redeploying but it only made it less functional. I would have thought the set up is correct but I am not able to receive any further help on this. Right now I could deploy it without the cookie config and just leave a note that this only has full functionality in Firefox.

first and foremost, before trying a bunch of random things, identify why it's working in firefox and not other browsers. That it's working in one major browser means something is going right at least, unless it's just caching or an extension you have running that's "fixing" a problem

I am not able to identify it. Firefox works in PrivateMode as well, which doesn't allow extensions in my set up.
The console just sends the message requests sent by the backend controllers if req.session.user isn't found.
Firefox is saving a cookie, but the other browsers are not.
But I am the frontend dev in this project, I am not well versed on cookies. The explanation I read about the additional cookie config
httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None',
made sense, as it is deployed on 2 different servers, but with it, it made things worse, and without it, its firefox only.

I mean... as an example, you should be able to see the cookie in the request payload. that shouldn't differ per browser, so does it contain what you expect to? do they appear on both browsers? If not... investigate that. If they do, determine why you think the cookie isn't being set. You need to get away from "doesn't work" to "X is wrong how do i fix it." If you don't know what's wrong... just throwing other solutions at it may "fix" it in a way that just breaks again later. You need to identify why it isn't working first.

When the site doesn't work, there is no cookie or request, when it does, its there.
I have made some partial progress. After searching further online, I found that people having the same issue with Render solved it by adding this config
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
before the App.use(sessions(config)) was declared.
I added this and made some progress. The site started working on Edge & Firefox (not Chrome) desktop. On mobile it worked on Edge, Chrome (surprisingly), on Brave it worked, but did not persist (closing the app draw meant the cookie was lost)... continued

It does not work on Samsung Web Browser.
So I dug a little deeper. My Brave Settings (mob, default) were to block 3rd party cookies. I allowed them and now Brave works like the others.
On Chrome (desktop) I did not have 3rd party cookies blocked, but I managed to get the website to work by explicitly adding the client URL to allowed cookies. However no cookie was found under site settting. I then found the cookie is saved under the server URL, which the other browsers were not doing.
On SamsungWebBrowser it still doesn't work, I allowed 3rd party cookies but this one remains an anomaly.
